# how do we define our Y values or labels in conv net for edge detection

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

Suppose if you are constructing a convnet that can perform edge detection. Then what i would do is train the convnet with original image as input and pre-processed edged images as my Y or output that i can use for comparing to get the loss, right?

Here is my question, **how can you define Y (label, categories, output whatever that make sense to you) as the pre-edged image so i can compare it at training time?**

should i not use relu or softmax? I mean say, **the results** from the last layer with classifier are ***100*** numbers indicating each pixels in **10x10** image in range form **0 to 1**. How can you compare those value(0~1) to the each pixel's value(0-255) from our Y or output (**pre-edged Image**)?

Comment: Apply a Sobel filter?

Comment: yep, that can be done for pre-edged image ...